# DNS resolving is slow only when using cURL to fetch data

Tags: dns, network-programming

I have domain 'engine02.prod.qc.offercal.com' in my local `bind9`.

I don't think it's DNS server or TTL issue, because the benchmark is almost always look like this (I tried for 2 minutes using each method) :

```
curl -o /dev/null http://engine02.prod.qc.offercal.com:49157/void

        time_namelookup:  0.150
           time_connect:  0.151
     time_starttransfer:  0.152
                        ----------
             time_total:  0.152

curl -o /dev/null http://192.168.100.10:49157/void # use IP directly

        time_namelookup:  0.000
           time_connect:  0.002
     time_starttransfer:  0.003
                        ----------
             time_total:  0.003

time dig @192.168.100.4 engine02.prod.qc.offercal.com

        real 0m0.009s
        user 0m0.004s
        sys  0m0.004s

time host engine02.prod.qc.offercal.com

        engine02.prod.qc.offercal.com has address 192.168.100.10
        real    0m0.011s
        user    0m0.006s
        sys     0m0.004s
```

My `resolv.conf` file:

```
[root@gateway01 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 192.168.100.4
```

I have been struggled with this issue for sometime, please help :D